# How to import .JSON file into mongoDB database

Tags: node.js, json, mongodb, rest

Can we import JSON file to MongoDB database according to the schema, without saving one by one using controller. Is there any way to import at once according to the schema
for ex -

JSON FILE -

```
    {
"Campaigns": {
    "-MWUAaJvqQpKGsB7QfSr": {
        "id": "-MWUAaJvqQpKGsB7QfSr",
        "imageUrl": "https://img.youtube.com/vi/SxPpleILQ4M/mqdefault.jpg",
        "link": "https://youtu.be/SxPpleILQ4M",
        "ownerId": "lW4ZfmutPOcNPsq4NSZ02y9NIiZ2"
    },
    "-MWUAtgSfA1JVbIqP77F": {
        "id": "-MWr5PhSt9r2gZQQWURm",
        "imageUrl": "https://img.youtube.com/vi/_fWQVHjPU_M/mqdefault.jpg",
        "link": "https://youtu.be/_fWQVHjPU_M",
        "ownerId": "AWgKC9VEyWgGBl9jl3vc0xPiAuR2",
        "setting": {
            "bill": "300",
            "dateTime": "2021.03.28 AD at 10:01:34",
            "expected_time": "30",
            "expected_views": "10",
            "types": "views"
        },
        "views": {
            "1Psi5NpOEFWREWg8QgRbPkOd6Zu2": true,
            "4LWTfJJoopMyLwkdAikF48HvyOw2": true,
            "OKuSRp6cvuXdycRf8IqZGmtV3o23": true,
            "WWDa5D5Nijf4FYnHXFj2YSxTRhz1": true,
            "XTkOU3xkyocVnZtDW8fqoxmJcSS2": true
        }
    }
},
"Users": {
    "25hc20XlzThPW0BBYHrNnmN2DZ83": {
        "coin": "240",
        "email": "maanhaary879@gmail.com",
        "id": "25hc20XlzThPW0BBYHrNnmN2DZ83",
        "image": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a-/AOh14Gjjh9RC3y_sac8Bo9k7z2TqRRDWiP_cLkYsoixn=s96-c",
        "referralCode": "MABM93BC",
        "userName": "maan fatteala",
        "vip": false
    },
    "26Oddmdf37fPj5oY0zVH1RmQJCh2": {
        "coin": "0",
        "email": "minolali39@gmail.com",
        "id": "26Oddmdf37fPj5oY0zVH1RmQJCh2",
        "image": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a/AATXAJwanRJUu3O2SzLVGFuHINrRqaNmwbfY6Qhynb1W=s96-c",
        "referralCode": "MIJIQWSC",
        "userName": "Mino Lali",
        "vip": false
    }
 }

}
```

is it possible to import json file to mongoDB db according to schema?

Comment: Using a shell script to import collection maybe?

Comment: yes boss, first I filtered my required collections, after that, i converted that into separate JSON and used mongoimport --jsonArray --db dbname --collection users --file C:\Users\Bhaskar\Desktop\apifolder\user.json